# How to tear down a GCD queue?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I have a GCD drawing queue to update my OpenGL ES scene which is structured like this:

```
- (void)drawFrame {
    dispatch_async(drawingQueue, ^{
        if (dispatch_semaphore_wait(frameRenderingSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW) != 0) {
            return;
        }

        @autoreleasepool {
            [self startDrawing];

            // drawing code

            [self endDrawing];
        }

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(frameRenderingSemaphore);
    });
}
```

When the app resigns active or enters background (both) I stop the OpenGL drawing run loop by invalidating the CADisplayLink.

The problem however is that dispatch_asyn dispatches a drawing block even until after the CADisplayLink got invalidated. When the user presses the home button, my app crashes because it attempted to draw a frame in OpenGL even though iOS teared down the context already.

Is there a way to kill / pause a GCD queue so it doesn't dispatch anything anymore?

Comment: `dispatch_suspend` will prevent additionally queued jobs from commencing, but does nothing with the currently running job. (I don't know which of those two scenarios applies here.)

Comment: In addition to Simon's suggestion, I might point out that your `dispatch_semaphore_wait()` is in the wrong place. It needs to be before `dispatch_async()`, not within your asynchronous block. The whole reason you'd use a semaphore like this is to prevent adding more than one rendering block on your GCD queue at a time, and the reason why you're seeing frames rendered after your application goes to the background is because a bunch of them have piled up in your queue. I bet you'll find this crashing going away after you move the wait to before your asynchronous dispatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to have a flag in your application that you check before executing the block. For example:

```
- (void)drawFrame {
    dispatch_async(drawingQueue, ^{

        if (appIsTerminated || appIsInBackground) {
            return;
        }

        if (dispatch_semaphore_wait(frameRenderingSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW) != 0) {
            return;
        }

        @autoreleasepool {
            [self startDrawing];

            // drawing code

            [self endDrawing];
        }

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(frameRenderingSemaphore);
    });
}
```

You can set those values in your app delegate in `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillTerminate`.

You could also try this:

```
dispatch_suspend(drawingQueue);
dispatch_release(drawingQueue);
```

Not quite sure about those though.

Here's all the details: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html

Comment: `dispatch_release` only reduces the retain count for the queue, allowing it to be deallocated once the retain count hits zero, so that's unlikely to help iFrog. `dispatch_suspend` is more promising, but is dependent upon whether the block is already running or not. (And if not running yet, your solution above is probably simpler.)

Comment: Thanks! Upvote requires 15 reputation. Would have done it :-)

Comment: You should be able to now! :)